# WPF C# Application does not show loading gif

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a gif into the program that will be shown during init of the actual app, as a splashscreen for WPF only takes static imgs(png etc).
I need to take a different route, i was hoping anyone could point me in the correct way.

Im figuring that i need to create a new thread for a form(so the gif doesn't freeze) and then displaying it somehow.
Help or example code would be appreciated, cheers guys

Comment: Please provide some code and more detail for more clarity.

Comment: As far as I know, the [`MediaElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement?view=netframework-4.8) is able to display GIF images. Try to set `MediaElement.Source` to the path of the .gif file.

Answer (score 1):

You should do various steps:

1. Install [this library](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif), that allow you put gifs in Image
   elements.
2. In the Window where you put your gif, set properties
   AllowsTransparency="True", Background="Transparent" and WindowStyle="None", and inside this window put your Image with the gif.
3. In the loaded event of the window, perform your code that initialize your app in a Task. In this way, your app will not freeze.
4. After initialization, show your main window y hide the window that
   contains your gif.

You also must set in the App.xaml, your property ShutdownMode="OnLastWindowClose".

I leave a [project](https://github.com/marlonedu/WpfTests/tree/master/WpfApp9) with this approach (check MainWindow and App.xaml)